# Yarn installed nyc successfully, but zsh says "command not found"

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, nyc

**Question:  How do I make nyc visible to zsh?**

Steps to recreate:

1. I tried `yarn add nyc -g` (I was following [steps](https://github.com/istanbuljs/puppeteer-to-istanbul#to-run-istanbul-reports) that used npm so I just replaced `npm i` with `yarn add`)
2. Then ran `nyc report --reporter=html`

> zsh: command not found: nyc

3. However, when I ran `npx nyc --help`, I got a full list of nyc functions!
4. Then I tried `yarn add -D` (from the [official nyc documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc))
5. Then ran `nyc report --reporter=text-lcov`. Once again:

> zsh: command not found: nyc

Comment: What directory is `nyc` installed in? Is that directory on your path?

Comment: @chepner now that I've installed it globally, it's in `/usr/local/bin/nyc`, but I don't know where it was before.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out I didn't install nyc globally.  If that's the case for you, you can run nyc by appending `npx` before any nyc command (which is why `npx nyc --help` was working).

If you want to install nyc globally with yarn, you have to do:
`yarn global add nyc`